# Unable to mock onKeyPress enter on input

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to mock my Add todo function, it should call the onCreateTodo function when pressed enter and if input is not null

input.component.tsx

```
if (e.key === "Enter") {
  if (!props.inputRef.current) return;
  props.onCreateTodo(props.inputRef.current.value);
}

<input
    ref={props.inputRef}
    id="todo-input"
    className="ToDo__input"
    placeholder="What needs to be done?"
    onKeyDown={onCreateTodo}
/>
```

input.test.tsx

```
const mountedComponent = mount(
  <TodoInput inputRef={inputMock} onCreateTodo={submitMock}
/>

it('Should call the onCreateTodo function when pressed enter', () => {
  expect(submitMock.mock.calls.length).toEqual(0);
  mountedComponent.simulate("change", { target: { value: "foo" } });
  mountedComponent.find('.ToDo__input').prop('onKeyDown')({ key: 'Enter' });
  expect(submitMock.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
});
```

the result is **Expected: 1** **Received: 0**

Comment: What's `inputMock`? Provide a minimal, reproducible, complete code example. How does the event handler trigger?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, `inputRef` must have  ` current.value !== '' `  and when i pressed `key enter` Should call the `onCreateTodo` function. The problem is i can't seem to chain

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try to use `simulate`

```
mountedComponent.find('.ToDo__input').simulate('keypress', {key: 'Enter'})
```

Another problem I can see here that you simulate your value on `mountedComponent` instead of `mountedComponent.find('.ToDo__input')`

Potential fix can be

```
mountedComponent.find('.ToDo__input').simulate("change", { target: { value: "foo" } });
```

Comment: I tried this but i'm still receiving 0

Comment: @clarkoy I think your value change also has a small problem. It should modify on input instead of `mountedComponent`. By the way, I modified my answer too

Comment: it was still failing `expect(submitMock.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1)` on this line

Comment: Now I have this 

`      expect(submitMock.mock.calls.length).toEqual(0);
      component.find('.ToDo__input').simulate("change", { target: { value: "foo" } });
      component.find('.ToDo__input').simulate('keypress', {key: 'Enter'})
      expect(submitMock.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
`

Comment: Could you share your full input component? I'd suggest that you also can try to add `console.log` on `onChange` to see it logged properly or not